# How can connections to a speadsheet-cell be found?

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice

How do I find out if the content of a spreadsheet-cell is used in the formula of other cells? In other words: how do I find connections with a cell?

Comment: Do you mean **Shift+F9**? (*Shift+F7* is mistakenly indicated in the [**Help**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/06030100.html?DbPAR=CALC&HID=.uno:ShowPrecedents#bm_id3145673)). Or do you want to find influencing cells in a macro? Then you need the method [**queryPrecedents**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XFormulaQuery.html#queryPrecedents)

Comment: I meant Trace Dependents (Shift-F5), but Shift-F9 is helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Tools" menu there is a sub menu "Detective" that you can use. See [the on-line help page](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/06030000.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id3151245) for more details. What you probably want to use is "Trace Dependents".

Comment: Great. 
When a cell is dependence or have precedents in another sheet, you see only a kind of flag. Is it possible to make it visible to or from which sheet(s) and cell(s)?

Comment: Hm, I always look into the formula in such cases. The GUI cannot draw arrows...